# How to grab the value of the output parameter in execute sp_executesql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please forgive newbie's ignorance!

How do I grab the value of the output parameter in execute sp_executesql?

I can see the output but cannot get to it:

```
    DECLARE @LastActivity nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @LastActivityDate datetime
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(MAX)
    DECLARE @RowsToProcess  int 
    DECLARE @CurrentRow     int 
    DECLARE @SelectCol1     nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @SelectCol2     nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @SelectCol3     nvarchar(100)
    DECLARE @LastDate TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), col4 nvarchar(MAX), col5 sql_variant)
    DECLARE @table1 TABLE (RowID int not null primary key identity(1,1), col1 nvarchar(100),col2 nvarchar(100),col3 nvarchar(100))
    INSERT into @table1 (col1,col2,col3)(SELECT t.name AS col1, c.name AS col2, m.Field1 as col3 
                                         FROM sys.columns c INNER JOIN 
                                              sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id INNER JOIN 
                                              sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id INNER JOIN 
                                              dbo.MERGE_TABLES m ON m.Table_Name=t.name
                                              WHERE c.name LIKE '%[_]DATE%' and m.[Enabled]='Y')  
    SET @RowsToProcess=@@ROWCOUNT 
    SET @CurrentRow=0 
    WHILE @CurrentRow<@RowsToProcess 
        BEGIN 
        SET @CurrentRow=@CurrentRow+1 
        SELECT @SelectCol1=col1,@SelectCol2=col2,@SelectCol3=col3 FROM @table1 WHERE RowID=@CurrentRow
            SET @sql='SELECT ' + '[dbo].[ConvertToDatetime](MAX(' + @SelectCol2 + '))' + ' FROM ' + @SelectCol1 + ' Where ' + @SelectCol3 + ' = ' + '''0722607QZ'''
        Declare @params as nvarchar(MAX)
        Set @params = '@date sql_variant output'
        Declare @date as sql_variant;
        execute sp_executesql 
                 @sql    
                ,@params 
                ,@date output
                       Select @date
        INSERT into @LastDate VALUES (@sql, @date) 
        end   
select col4,col5 from @LastDate
```

select col4,col5 from @LastDate gives me the SQL script in clo4 but col5 is empty! I need to store the @date as I still need to get the Max(@date)

Thanx a million.

> SET @sql='set @date =('SELECT ' + '[dbo].[ConvertToDatetime](MAX(' +
>   @SelectCol2 + '))' + ' FROM ' + @SelectCol1 + ' Where ' + @SelectCol3
>   + ' = ' + '''0722607QZ''' ) '

the above sql gives me error: Incorrect syntax near '.'

> SET @sql='set @date =(SELECT   [dbo].[ConvertToDatetime](MAX( + @SelectCol2 + ))
>   FROM   @SelectCol1   Where   @SelectCol3  ''=0722607QZ'' ) '

The above sql gives the error: Must declare the scalar variable "@SelectCol2"

```
SET @sql='SELECT ' + @date + '=convert(nvarchar(100), [dbo].[ConvertToDatetime](MAX(' + @SelectCol2 + ')))' + ' FROM ' + @SelectCol1 + ' Where ' + @SelectCol3 + ' = ' + '''0722607QZ'''
```

> the above produces the error : Implicit conversion from data type sql_variant to nvarchar is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

```
SET @sql='SELECT ' + @date + '=convert(nvarchar(MAX),(MAX(' + @SelectCol2 + '))' + ' FROM ' + @SelectCol1 + ' Where ' + @SelectCol3 + ' = ' + '''0722607QZ'''
```

> the above produces no error but all output is NULL, no values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax looks ok but you never assign to the output variable @date hence no value.

Instead of;

```
SET @sql='SELECT ...'
```

You need;

```
SET @sql='set @date = (SELECT ...'
```

Can't you use a better type than `sql_variant`?

Comment: You are a very kind genius! However I get an error: Incorrect syntax near '.' though. Any ideas?

Comment: Whereabouts? what do values of @sql look like?

Comment: It does not run. I marked it as the answer because I am sure that will fix it, but for now it gives me the error

Comment: Comments did not allow the sql, so I pasted it on the question as the last row

Comment: dates are not always datetime :) - some are int, some are char(8),etc. so I have no choice..

Comment: on the SET @sql='set @date = (SELECT ...)' line

Comment: Do the names in the @SelectCol variables contain invalid characters? if so escape them with [] `...(MAX([' + @SelectCol2 + ']))' ...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4093/discussion-between-greg-and-alex-k)